# Acumatica Unable to find Dataview in Lookup Grid

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am trying to Add a UDF in "Add Stock Item" dialog box of Sales Order screen. Unfortunately i am ending up with an warning message
"The siteStatus view is not found. Try to publish the customization project", though i have published the customization project several time but the message didn't go.

here is the screen below

[Customization Editor Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEVIk.png)

The Acumatica version i am using is  18.106.0026 (2018R1).
What is the issue here and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately i found the solution....
the data-member property of the Grid which the data-view corresponds to have a spell mistake i.e. a capital letter 'S' as "siteStatus" (refer question above), the view name will be actually "sitestatus" with a small  's' this was the only difference, Change the dataview name in the datamember property of the Grid and its done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Code samples included in the question would help a lot.  However, the most common cause in my experience has been that the graph you reference in the DataSource is either missing, incorrect, or incomplete... or just inaccessible by the customization project at the moment.

First, check your DataSource defined for the screen.  Make sure that it properly references your Namespace and Class from your graph.  On the screen editor, click on the DataSource node and navigate to the TypeName field.  It should be the fully qualified path to your class.  For example, PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItemMaint would point to the InventoryItemMaint graph defined in the PX.Objects.IN namespace.

[image]

If this is a custom graph, make sure your class is part of the customization project.  If it is defined in Visual Studio, be sure you have compiled it and added the DLL to the project under the Files node of the project.

[image]

If it is defined directly in the Customization Project, you must successfully publish your project for the code to take effect.  In the following example, the TypeName would be Blog.BlogMaint but won't be available for use in defining a screen until the project has been published at least once.  Afterwards, the TypeName can be specified ast Blog.BlogMaint and then the form/grid DataMember can be set to TestView as specified in the graph.

[image]

Early on, I struggled for a long time myself in getting my class accessible to the project before naming it in the TypeName property of the DataSource, so just keep at it until you get it working.  It will get easier with time.

If none of these help, are you getting errors when you try to publish your project?

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for ur reply. Unfortunately the dataview i am working with is a system data view (siteStatus), this dataview is defined for ADD STOCK ITEM Dialog in the SO screen's Document Details tab for which this error message is showing up. the steps which you have explained above will work perfectly well for a customized data view.